# C# OdbcDataReader storedproc call with params returns no data

Tags: c#, .net

I think there is something trivial that I am overlooking where with this issue, I am calling a stored proc, I know the call is made as I can see it in profiler, and when I run the stored proc from query analyzer it does return records as intended. Problem is when I call it from C# code, execution is happening but no results are retrieved.

What my debugging has revealed that if I have a code such as
    if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##base') IS NOT NULL drop table ##base
in the stored procedure, it would not return any data using OdbcDataReader, otherwise it would return data, Can some one tell me why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code example.  We can't tell you what's wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that the results returned to .NET are those of the LAST statement that issued a SELECT in the procedure.  If the OBJECT_ID query is AFTER the SELECT statement you want returning data then you're probably not going to get results.

However, I would need to see your stored procedures to tell you for sure.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

ALTER         PROCEDURE dbo.proc_myStoredProc
AS

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##base') IS NOT NULL drop table ##base
SELECT * FROM mytable
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

If I remove the drop table statement above I get the data otherwise no

**HOW TO CHECK FOR AND DROP A TEMP TABLE**

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/17/sql-server-how-to-drop-temp-table-check-existence-of-temp-table/

Comment: There is nothing much in SP
Here is code

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

GO SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.proc_myStoredProc AS

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##base') IS NOT NULL drop table ##base

SELECT * FROM mytable

GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF GO SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

If I remove the drop table statement above I get the data otherwise no

Comment: Are you sure the DROP TABLE statement isn't throwing an error and the procedure is just failing?  That would explain why you get no results.  I've never seen a temporary table accessed with two pound signs before.  Doesn't mean it can't work, I've just never seen it.

Comment: In other words I think if you drop the `##` and replace it with `#` you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes I am sure drop table is not throwing any errors as I can run the sp through quer analyzer with no issue and it returns correct data. I removed ## and rplaced it with # but still no luck